# Prevent Browser From Obscuring Page

Tags: browser, htc-sense

The default browser (at least on HTC Sense) has this annoying habit of sliding the address bar down over the top portions of websites while the page is loading. After the page loads, the address bar is still there but it doesn't cover anything anymore. This is particularly annoying on sites like stackoverflow where it perfectly covers the top navigation area. Any way to make it stop?

More Information:

I wasn't aware of this before but this behavior is due to the fact that the phone's status bar decides to make itself visible while a page is loading. The amount of page covered is equal to the height of the status bar. This has to be a bug. Either the status bar isn't supposed to become visible or the height calculations don't take it into account -- the page needs to be shifted down by address_bar_height + status_bar_height.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution for this problems specifically, but have you tried using [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com)? It's a mobile-friendly ubersite for all Stack Exchange sites.